# Module an permission issues

Tags: 7, users

I have a custom module called 'products'

I set the access options like so:

```
function products_permission() {
  return array(
    'access products' => array(
      'title' => t('TBYT Products'),
      'description' => t('Administer TBYT Products'),
    )
  );
}
```

In the admin I have enabled the module and gave everyone this permission.

Then I defined:

```
function products_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['products/list'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

    'title' => 'Enjoy shopping',

    'page callback' => 'html_list_products',      

    'access arguments' => array('access products')
  );

   return $items;
}
```

This works fine, however I need to now make the URI dynamic, so I added something like:

```
  $items['products/list/%/%'] = array(
```

I also added the appropriate page arguments:

```
'page arguments' => array(2, 3),
```

However when I rebuild the cache and I access:

**products/list/23**

it works fine but when I access

**products/list**

I get:

*The requested page "/products/list" could not be found.*

Comment: Just occurred to me...do I just add multiple menu item entries, one with a argument placeholder and one without???

Comment: That did the trick but now I have 3 menu items all calling the same callback -- seems kinda redundant. Frameworks like Zend/Symphony, etc allow for dynamic routing...is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing the (correct) conclusions you've come to in the comments...

Yes, you'll see some repetition in Drupal 6/7. Drupal 8 uses Symfony routes so things get better, but it's not stable yet.

For your specific case you don't *have* to have 3 separate menu items (although for the sake of clarity it might make sense). You can define a single list page like so

```
function products_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['products/list'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'title' => 'Enjoy shopping',
    'page callback' => 'html_list_products',      
    'access arguments' => array('access products')
  );

  return $items;
}
```

And define your page callback like so

```
function html_list_products($arg1 = NULL, $arg2 = NULL) {
  if ($arg1 && arg2) {
    // Both args were provided.
  }
  elseif ($arg1) {
    // Just the first arg was provided.
  }
  else {
    // No args were provided.
  }
}
```

Drupal will always pass along the remaining slash-separated parts of the request URL to the callback function, so with the above method if you visit `/products/list/1/2`, `$arg1` and `$arg2` will be populated respectively. Similarly if you visit `/products/list/1` just `$arg1` will be populated, and for `/products/list`, neither will be.

Comment: I tried that...with default parameters and I still received a permission issue...or rather Page not Found error?!? Only when I added each URI route did the page error stop occurring

Comment: Are you clearing the caches after changing things in `hook_menu()`? I can't think of any reason the above wouldn't work

Comment: Yeppers I sure am :) It's like drupal uses a static router...so it literally maps on a URI by URI basis with dynamic placeholders to allow for URI variables. No worries though everything works as expected despite a bit of duplication. A bit of clever code could address that but it's not major

Comment: Search "Dynamic Paths" pretty sure it demonstrates what were talking about: https://drupal.org/node/1800686